# How can I configure WP multisite to use /blog/ as part of the path structures?

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting

I'm migrating an existing group of sites to multisite using subdirectories and need to match the url paths exactly, and am running into conflicts with the /blog/ path that gets inserted by default on the root install, among other things. I've combed all of the multiple posts on this, but haven't found an answer to my specific problem, so here goes.

I'm trying to achieve the following:

- example.com/blog (english language blog)
- example.com/fr/blog (french)
- example.com/ja/blog (japanese)

etc.

Multisite restricts you from using /blog/ as it is inserted into the root install paths by default, and same goes for using it in a subpath, ie. /fr/blog. Any ideas? I'm completely stumped.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only one thing I can see to solve this problem is to use redirection by .htaccess.

But my question is, why don't you manage to redirect old URLs to the new version, without the /blog ? Because I guess, your concern is most about SEO no ?

redirect 301 /blog/ http://www.yourdomain.com/

Comment: Yes, SEO is the main concern here - apparently Facebook is particularly picky about changes in URLs.